# Django: как хранить jwt?

Tags: python, django

При запросе к сервису доставки получаю jwt на час. Где и как правильно хранить jwt-токен получаемый от стороннего api? Думал хранить в бд, но мне кажется такой подход не совсем правильный или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Как вариант - использование кеша. При логине сохраняете токен в кеш с указанием времени жизни и пользуетесь им пока он там есть. Если токен не обнаружен то нужно перелогиниться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хранить в кэше

Ответил @5c0rp в комментарии к вопросу.